# CSS and JS files sometimes can't load on our Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, caching, content-management-system

I have trouble to get and know about this issue.
We have our website which is built on Wordpress CMS. One month ago, I did some website optimization related to website speed, because our website loads too slow.

But after doing some stuffs by using wp-optimize and wp-fastest-cache plugin. Our website sometimes may not loads CSS and JS files properly at the time of loading.

While visiting our some website pages, it will loads only content and images.

Why it was happening? There is any solution to overcomes from this problem.

Thanks,
Gopal Kshirsagar

Comment: the problem only have description but no code and not other information

Comment: Upload Your script in `CloudFlare` or use some script that it has for free. maybe your host has low speed.

Comment: @brk - I think it may cause due to some code which is in .htaccess file, can i share that code?

Comment: remove `.htaccess` to find problem.

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: Error in console: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Its issue due to minify css and js

Comment: So don't minify the css and js it will work for you.

Comment: Ok dipmala, for that i have to removed that code from website.